# Mapping is not working inside react-bootstrap-carousel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap carousel . And I wanted to use mapping inside it. But it is not working. Can someone help me with that

```
import React from "react";
import "../../styles/Banner.css";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";

const data = [
  "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1680/280/image/1defb861e409319b.jpg?q=50",
  " https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1680/280/image/685712c6cefb3c02.jpg?q=50",
  "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1680/280/image/8d4150cc4f3f967d.jpg?q=50",
  "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1680/280/image/685712c6cefb3c02.jpg?q=50",
];

const Banner = () => {
  return (
    <Carousel className="carasousel">
      <Carousel.Item>
        {data.map((imag, i) => {
          return (
            <>
              <img src={imag} alt="img" key={i} className="banner_img" />
            </>
          );
        })}
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default Banner;
```

It supposed to show one item at a time but it is showing all four together.

Another Issue:
And I also wanted to remove the lower slide indicator from the carousel . Is there any way to remove it.

[image: Wanted to remove this indicator]

Comment: I've not looked at react-bootstrap-carousel but purely off naming alone one might assume that `Carousel.Item` is an individual item/slide and you have put all 4 of your images inside that single item/slide.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
  {data.map((imag, i) => (
      
          <img src={imag} alt="img" key={i} className="banner_img" />
      
    ))}
```